# На ru.SO, у четвертого пункта в меню тревоги отсутствует перевод его второго подпункта

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

...что выглядит еще более забавно *the scope is defined in some справка*, где "справка" является единственным переведённым словом в этом предложении.

> [image]